# Select multiple columns but group by only one column in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Select Multiple columns but group by only one column

```
const categories = await Course.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id', 'category',
        [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('category')), 'count'],
    ],
    raw: true,
    group: ['Course.category']
})
```

I am getting error:

```
original: error: column "Course.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Have you tried `group: [ 'category' ]`?

Comment: This is common Postgres error because SQL doesn't know which `id` to show if you group by `category`. For example, if `id: 1,3,8,10` has the same `category`, which `id` do you want to have in an output?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is for an aggregation that means to get some summarized rows which in general not equal to original rows and thus might not have all PK values of original rows.